# Call Flow Note/Fom Using JS/HTML

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I'm trying to create an HTML form using Javascript that copies the contents of each field and Pastes's it into a singular textbox.

HTML CODE PROVIDED

```
<h1><a>Call Flow Cheat Sheet</a></h1>

<form id="callflow" class="appnitro"  method="post" action="">

<div class="form_description">

<h2>Callflow</h2>

<p>Flowsheet to take notes and ensure you meet all QA elements on every call.</p>

</div>                      

<ul >

<li id="li_1" >

<label class="description" for="cust_name">Greet Customer </label> <br> 
Thank you for calling ___________ My Name is David to Whom do I have the Pleasure of Speaking with today? <br><br>
<label class="description" for="cust_name"> Customer Name</label>
<div>
<input id="cust_name" name="cust_name" class="element text medium" type="text" maxlength="255" value=""/> 
<br>
</div>
<label class="description" for="call_reason">Reason for the call. </label>
<div>
<textarea id="call_reason" name="call_reason" class="element textarea medium"></textarea> 
</div>  
</li>

<li id = "li_2" >
<label class="description" for="element_2">Provide Assurance Statement </label>
<p>____________ I want to personally apologize that your having to deal with this if this happened to me I would be fustrated as well.</p> <br>


</li>
<li id = "li_3" >
<label class="description" for="element_3">Provide Promoter Statement </label>
<p> This is not the experience we want our customers to have here at ______________. I would be more than happy to take care this for you. </p><br>
</li>

<li id="li_4" >
<label class="description" for="element_4">Ask Probing Questions:</label>
Why do you want to return [insert item]? <br>
Can I ask why your seeking to cancel your order? <br>
Was this item for an event? <br>
Could you describe the damage to me? 
<br>
<br>  
</li>
<li id = "li_5">
<label class="description" for="tailored_solution"> Propose Solution </label>
<p>D. Discount to keep. | R. Replacement Parts | U. Unit | M. Money Back</p> 
<br>
<div>
<textarea id="tailored_solution" name="tailored_solution" class="element textarea medium"></textarea> 
</div>
<br>
<br>
<label class="description" for="tailored_solution"> WRAP Call </label>

<p> It's going to take just a brief moment here for me to finish up processing this request for you. You wont hear anything but rest assured I am still here just holler if you need anything.  </p>
</li>
<li id="li_6" >

<label class="description" for="set_expectations">Recap & Set Expectations. </label>

<span>

<input id="set_expectations_discount" name="set_expectations_discount" class="element checkbox" type="checkbox" value="1" />

<label class="choice" for="set_expectations_discount">Discount Expectations</label>

<input id="set_expectations_replacement" name="set_expectations_replacement" class="element checkbox" type="checkbox" value="1" />

<label class="choice" for="set_expectations_replacement">Replacement Expectations</label>

<input id="set_expectations_refund" name="set_expectations_refund" class="element checkbox" type="checkbox" value="1" />

<label class="choice" for="set_expectations_refund">Refund Expectations</label>

<input id="set_expectations_return" name="set_expectations_return" class="element checkbox" type="checkbox" value="1" />

<label class="choice" for="set_expectations_return">Return Expectations</label>

</span> 

</li>
<li id="li_7" >

<label class="description" for="close">Check for Additional Needs Addressing  any Remaining Questions. </label>

<span>

<input id="close_1" name="close_1" class="element checkbox" type="checkbox" value="1" />

<label class="choice" for="close_1">Yes</label>

<input id="close_2" name="close_2" class="element checkbox" type="checkbox" value="1" />

<label class="choice" for="close_2">No</label>

</span> 
</li>
<li id = "li_8">
<label class="description" for="notes"> Generate Notes  </label>
<input type="checkbox" name="notes_gen" onclick="FillNotes(this.form)">
<em>Check this box to generate notes.</em>
<div>
<textarea id="notes" name="notes" class="element textarea medium"></textarea> 
</div>


<li class="buttons">

<input type="hidden" name="form_id" value="6865" />


<input id="clearForm" class="button_text" type="reset" name="Clear" value="Clear" />

</li>

</ul>

</form> 

<div id="footer">
        <a>Created by David Desilets Associate SSC 1</a>


</div>

</div>

<img id="bottom" src="bottom.png" alt="">

</body>

</html>
```

Javascript Code Provided

```
function FillNotes(f) {
  if(f.notes.checked == true) {
    f.notes.value = f.cust_name.value;
    f.notes.value = f.call_reason.value;
    f.notes.value = f.tailored_solution.value;
    f.notes.value = f.set_expectations.value;
    f.notes.value = f.set_expectations_discount.value;
    f.notes.value = f.set_expectations_refund.value;
    f.notes.value = f.set_expectations_replacement.value;
    f.notes.value = f.set_expectations_return.value;
    f.notes.value = f.close.value;
    f.notes.value = f.close_1.value;
    f.notes.value = f.close_2.value;
  }
}
```

Now I want it to Copy the contents of each checkbox & text area except the last textbox where I want it to paste into and add a separator between each entry like | or /

Firstly What am I doing wrong 2nd'y my JS is subpar at best. Would someone be willing to help me?

PS the submit button has been replaced with reset as this is intended to be a replacement for "notetaking" at work so we can remove access to sticky notes on agent computers.

Answer (score 0):

When you assign to an element's value with `=`, just like with any other assignment operation, the previous value has no connection to the property anymore; it will disappear. You should either *concatenate* instead, so that the strings will be joined together, rather than continuously replace each other:

```
function FillNotes(f) {
  if(f.notes.checked == true) {
    f.notes.value = f.cust_name.value;
    f.notes.value += f.call_reason.value;
    f.notes.value += f.tailored_solution.value;
    f.notes.value += f.set_expectations.value;
    f.notes.value += f.set_expectations_discount.value;
    f.notes.value += f.set_expectations_refund.value;
    f.notes.value += f.set_expectations_replacement.value;
    f.notes.value += f.set_expectations_return.value;
    f.notes.value += f.close.value;
    f.notes.value += f.close_1.value;
    f.notes.value += f.close_2.value;
  }
}
```

Or, it would be a lot better if you came up with a single string to start with, and *then* assigned that string to `f.notes.value`:

```
function FillNotes(f) {
  if(f.notes.checked !== true) return;
  const props = [
    'cust_name',
    'call_reason',
    'tailored_solution',
    'set_expectations',
    'set_expectations_discount',
    'set_expectations_refund',
    'set_expectations_replacement',
    'set_expectations_return',
    'close',
    'close_1',
    'close_2',
  ];
  const newValue = props.reduce((strSoFar, prop) => strSoFar + f[prop].value + '\n', '')
  f.notes.value = newValue;
}
```

Comment: so the single string you mentioned newValue could be named as gen_notes and that value would be assigned to an empty text area to dump it into?

Comment: You can name variables however you wish (with a few restrictions), names won't change anything as long as you don't duplicate them. The current `FillNotes` function does require that whatever `f.notes` refers to is a `textarea`, though (which can be empty, or not - whatever you want)

Comment: last question ... i think can i delimit them like you can in excel where cell a + this text + cell b = cell c  (sorry for the nightmares lol...)              
    cust_name + called in + because of + call_reason + tailored_solution + educated customer on + set_expectations_refund + close_1

Comment: I was delimiting them with `\n`, feel free to substitute in any other string you want in there.